# I have 10 csv files in array and I want row count of each csv file using perl

Tags: csv, perl

I have 10 CSV files in `@files`. Now I want to count the number rows in each CSV file. I have tried the below code but it's returning me only CSVs count.

```
my $directory = 'C:\folder';
open "dir", $directory or die;
@files = readdir "dir";
close("dir");
```

Please help me to achieve above scenario.

Comment: If you in Unix/Linux then you could just use `wc -l file1 file2 file3 ... filen`.

Comment: You can't just count lines in some cases because quoted fields might have newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $directory = "/path/to/the/directory/";
my @files = glob("$directory*.csv");

foreach my $file (@files){
    my $lines = 0;
    open (FILE, $file) or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
    $lines++ while (<FILE>);
    close FILE;

    print "File:$file = $lines\n";
}
```

Tested it in Ubuntu 20.04 (Perl v5.30.0).

Comment: Why not to use `my @lines = <FILE>; say scalar @lines`? Or do you expect huge files?

Comment: @PolarBear: Yes, that's also possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a FAQ.

[How do I count the number of lines in a file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#How-do-I-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file?)

The answer discusses a number of ways to approach the problem, before deciding:

> If you don't mind shelling out, the wc command is usually the fastest, even with the extra interprocess overhead. Ensure that you have an untainted filename though:
>
> ```
> #!perl -T
>
> $ENV{PATH} = undef;
>
> my $lines;
> if( $filename =~ /^([0-9a-z_.]+)\z/ ) {
>     $lines = `/usr/bin/wc -l $1`
>     chomp $lines;
> }
> ```